# vb.net extract zip from resources

Tags: vb.net

So, I want to extract a zip file using a dll from my program resources, I'm using Ionic library.

```
Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim zipFileStream As Stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("My.Resources.file.zip")

        Using zip1 As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(zipFileStream)
                Dim es As ZipEntry
                zip1.Password = "elissan69$"
            ' here, we extract every entry, bu1t we could extract conditionally,
            ' based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.   
            For Each entry As ZipEntry In zip1
                entry.Extract(UnpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
            Next
        End Using
```

I got an error .. on zipfile.read .. File cannot be NULL

Comment: a.GetManifestResourceStream is probably returning null.  Are you sure the ZIP is embedded in the currently executing assembly and that the name is exactly correct?

Comment: I have a file.zip on my program resources.